# How to disable back button functionality until a task is completed inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using single activity as a container for my fragments, my second fragment in its onCreate method runs a for loop in coroutine scope, but if the user presses the system's back button the app crashes with null pointer exception...How can I disable the back button functionality until my coroutine job is completed?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setClickListeners()
    //This creates buttons on the layout dynamically
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        delay(100)
        for (i in 0 until runTillAndHowMany) {
            createButton()
            delay(25)
        }
    }

}
```

I know this is way too wrong to use GlobalScope like this in onCreate, but didn't find any alternative, I want that animation of custom buttons getting created one by one on screen.

I'm using NavigationComponent library, and Transition Animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a boolean variable to handle this. So in your Activity you can declare it like this:

```
var shouldGoBack: Boolean = false
```

And then you override your onBackPressed method to go as follows

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   if(shouldGoBack)
     super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Finally you access the variable on your Fragment and set it to true once the coroutine is done like this:

```
(activity as YourActivity).shouldGoBack = true
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: It worked, I also had to reset the boolean to false again once I come back from the fragment, right now I'm writing this line `(activity as YourActivity).shouldGoBack = true` in the for loop which is creating the button, with this condition    `if (i == runTillAndHowMany-1)`